# TypeScript Compiler API How to set Lib?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I am using the [TypeScript Compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) which literally has no documentation so hopefully someone can help here.

I'm trying to add in the `ES2020` lib option to my compiler options when running `ts.createProgram`.

I found out that `"lib"` is a `string[]` [where the `CompilerOptions` interface is defined here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9ff24b6fc87dd4a376a434d1019d356dfe743c53/lib/protocol.d.ts).

I tried setting lib as follows:

```
const program = ts.createProgram(files, {
    target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES2020,
    module: ts.ModuleKind.ES2015,
    lib: ["ES2020"], // <---
    ...
}, host);
```

This seems to not be working, I am getting constant compilation errors stating `Cannot find name 'Array/Number/Math'`, etc, so the lib is clearly not being defined correctly.

How can I set the lib correctly???

---

Edit: I have a custom host object, with the following function which may be relevant to the question:

```
getDefaultLibFileName(options) {
    return ts.getDefaultLibFilePath(options);
}
```

Comment: What does `host` look like? Perhaps that's not searching in the correct place for `node_modules`.

Comment: @DavidSherret I don't have any `node_modules` in my code that's being compiled. Anyway I'm trying to fix language built-ins such as `Math`, not anything from a node module.

Comment: @DavidSherret I have a custom host, I've updated the question to show something that might be relevant.

Comment: curious what you need to do that you can't do with `tsc`

Comment: @inorganik custom module resolution, and rewriting imports :)

Answer (score 3):

it worked for me if I put the entire filename inside the `lib` field, like;

```
{
  ...
  lib: ['lib.esnext.d.ts', 'lib.dom.d.ts'],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

<strike>"I don't have any node_modules in my code that's being compiled." I believe this is the reason it's not working. The host will look at the code's `node_modules` folder to find the `lib.es20202.full.d.ts` file.</strike>

See the result of `ts.getDefaultLibFilePath(options)` in the host and I think it will be a file that doesn't exist.

To fix this, ensure the custom host provides the file path to a `.d.ts` file that exists or have the host provide the text of the file the compiler is searching for (this could be done in memory using the host).

Comment: Wow, that makes a lot of sense, I'll try that! :)

Comment: What do you mean by the host's node_modules folder? I still have a node_modules folder along with my code that uses the compiler API, but the code *that is being compiled* does not have a node_modules folder... so I think it should actually still work. I tried updating the function to return the exact location to the lib file `lib.es2020.full.d.ts` and that hasn't fixed anything.

Comment: @DavidCallanan I misremembered where it gets the lib files from, but yes you are right that it will use the current compiler's node_module's folder. Check the calls the compiler makes to all the `readFile` and `fileExists` on the host and ensure those files exist. If that doesn't work, then I'm not sure what's wrong without seeing more code.

Comment: Something is fishy... if I remove the lib option entirely, but keep my getDefaultLibFileName function the same (returning the lib.es2020 file), the errors go away. Hopefully that stays working... thanks for all the help anyways!